# Read-only vs auto (read-only) property

Tags: f#, f#-3.0

Is there a difference between using a read-only property:

```ml
type T(arg) =
  member x.M = arg
```

and using an automatically implemented property:

```ml
type T(arg) =
  member val M = arg
```

assuming `arg` has no side effects? Any reason to prefer one over the other?

Comment: In my experience, there is not much noticable difference between them - Whichever feels more understandable when reading the code as a whole.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The essential difference between those is that `member val` represents an expression that is computed **only once** during instance initialization. Therefore,

```
type Person(fname, lname) =
  member val Name = fname + lname // would be calculated once
```

So, the first consideration is performance.

Another consideration is based on two limitations of auto properties:

- you can only use them in types with primary ctor;
- they can't be `virtual`

Comment: The limitations are noteworthy. Perhaps I didn't phrase it well, but I meant to assume `arg` is a simple value such as a literal. That, as far as I know, eliminates the cost difference.

Comment: I prefer the auto syntax for the absence of a `this` reference. It makes it clear that it neither mutates the object nor depends on other members.